# Any Java API or free MySQL Database for City-from-country mapping with ISO codes?

Tags: mysql, iso, java

This is my requirement:

1. I need to populate all **countries** of the world in a dropdown (combobox).
2. There would be another dropdown just below that shall be populated with values of **cities of the selected country**.
3. All the countries and cities shall have their respective **ISO codes** when shown in the dropdowns.

I am looking for either a free available database in mysql (I have not been able to find one; all are either paid or inconsistent)- or - preferably a Java API which can return me countries and cities so that I do not have to store the entire database at my end.

Technologies used: MySQL, JSF.

Any help shall be highly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://opengeocode.org/download.php will help, see e.g. the "Cities of the World". It's a CSV you could import into MySQL. You can see the data structure by clicking on the "Metadata" button. Good luck!

Comment: I downloaded the CSV - the name column does not contain names of the cities. Rather, the values of latitude & longitude have shifted one column left, overlapping the names column, and longitude column is blank.  
I also need the ISO code of each city.  Thanks so much for this.